# Protractor locator for multiple elements with same formControlName

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to locate an element which is text field, and provided with formControlName. But the formControlName is same for all the input fields that comes after clicking on the add button. So how can i insert into the nth text field with same formControlName? how to fetch the total count of elements with same formControlName?

I am new to this automation using protractor, please do help.

We are currently using cucumber framework with protractor javascript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the total count of elements with same formcontrolname can be achieved by using

```
var count = await element.all(by.xpath("ElementXpath")).count();
```

If you want to input to nth element it can be done by providing the number with the locator for example,

```
//input[name='subject'][3]
```

here,it will select the 3rd input with name subject from top to bottom order